# Taking picture from camera or gallery in to dialog box when submitting the activity got refreshing and make it empty

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragmentactivity, android-lifecycle

In my app using one `dialog box` to for adding review.In that box give a button for taking images from `camera` or `gallery` and and make the review and rating.But the problem is when submitting after filling the fields only rating and ,review got saved and image is not saving.From checking i understood that after taking images from `camera` or `gallery` the activity got `refreshed` because of the `function OnRestart()` .If commended`OnRestart` the image also saving.But i cant avoid the function according my code hierarchy it will effect other cases like logout. so please suggest some way to achieve these things.Answer will be appreciated.Below i will give the dialog code for my activity.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
public InterfaceCommunicator interfaceCommunicator;

private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION = 2;
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo",
        "Choose from Library",
        "Cancel"};
 private RatingBar ratingBar;
 private AppCompatTextView choose_file;
 private ImageView pic_file;
 private EditText review_text;
 private Button Submit;
 private final String LOG_TAG = MyDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName();

 private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_PROOF = 100;
 private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_KEY_CODE = 110;
 private static int GALLERY_REQUEST_PROOF = 101;
 private static int GALLERY_REQUEST_KEY_CODE = 111;
 private Bitmap bitmap;
 private String imageRating ="no";

// onCreate --> (onCreateDialog) --> onCreateView --> onActivityCreated
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
  container, 
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onCreateView");

    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_review, container, 
  false);

    choose_file = (AppCompatTextView) 
   dialogView.findViewById(R.id.choose_file);
    ratingBar = (RatingBar) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    review_text = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.review);
    pic_file = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.pick_file);
    Submit = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnreview);
    pic_file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        //pickImageSingle();
                                        int result = 
           ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), 
           Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                                        int result1 = 
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), 
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                                        if ( result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                            if (result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                                takePhoto();
                                            } else {
                                                alert();
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            buildAlertMessageNoCamera();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    });
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
            float rate = ratingBar.getRating();
            System.out.println("ProfileView.onRatingChanged " + rate);
        }
    });

    Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String review = review_text.getText().toString().trim();
            float rate = ratingBar.getRating();
            String rating = String.valueOf((int) rate);

            if (!review.isEmpty() && !rating.isEmpty()) {
                interfaceCommunicator.sendRequestCode(rating, rate, 
           review,imageRating);
              //  setReviewApi(rating, rate, review, dialog);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Please enter the credentials!", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
    return dialogView;
}

  // If shown as dialog, set the width of the dialog window
// onCreateView --> onActivityCreated -->  onViewStateRestored --> 
  onStart --> onResume
 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
    if (getShowsDialog()) {
        // Set the width of the dialog to the width of the screen in 
   portrait mode
        DisplayMetrics metrics = 
      getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int dialogWidth = Math.min(metrics.widthPixels, 
     metrics.heightPixels);
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
}

private void showToast(String buttonName) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on \"" + buttonName + "\"", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

// If dialog is cancelled: onCancel --> onDismiss
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onCancel");
}

// If dialog is cancelled: onCancel --> onDismiss
// If dialog is dismissed: onDismiss
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"onDismiss");
}
private void takePhoto() {
    try {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
    AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(Constants.ProfileFragment.ADD_PHOTO);
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                if 
   (items[item].equals(Constants.ProfileFragment.TAKE_PHOTO)) {

                    Intent cameraIntent = new 
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    //    buildAlertMessageNoCamera();
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 
       CAMERA_REQUEST_PROOF);

} else if 
  (items[item].equals(Constants.ProfileFragment.FROM_LIBRARY)) {

                    Intent galleryintent = new 
   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(galleryintent, 
GALLERY_REQUEST_PROOF);

                } else if 
   (items[item].equals(Constants.ProfileFragment.CANCEL)) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void alert() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
}

private void buildAlertMessageNoCamera() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
  data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_PROOF) {
        final Bitmap photo;
        try {
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            bitmap = photo;
            imageRating = getStringImage(bitmap);
            File photopath = null;
            photopath = saveToInternalStorage(photo);
             choose_file.setText("1 item selected");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_PROOF && (data != null)) {
        try {
            Uri selected_image = data.getData();
            String[] filepath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = 
 getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selected_image, filepath, 
      null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columIntex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filepath[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columIntex);
            cursor.close();
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = 
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            bitmap = yourSelectedImage;
            imageRating = getStringImage(bitmap);
            choose_file.setText("1 item selected");
            Log.e("checkImages",imageRating);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
private String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, 
  Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
private File saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if 
   (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        }
    }
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getActivity());
    File directory = cw.getDir("patientphoto", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(5000) + 1;
    File path = new File(directory, "" + num + ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream stream = null;

    try {
        stream = new FileOutputStream(path);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
    return path;
}
public interface InterfaceCommunicator {
    //  setReviewApi(rating, rate, review, dialog);
    void sendRequestCode(String rating, float rate, String 
     review,String imageRating);

}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        interfaceCommunicator = (InterfaceCommunicator) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(getTargetFragment().toString() + " 
   must implement ConfirmDeletePopupFragment.DialogListener");
    }
    }

     }
```

Comment: Of course if your activity is behind another activity or app it can be killed at any time by Android OS. (First lesson).  You have to acommodate for that. Implement onSaveInstanceState() to begin with.

Comment: `In my app using one dialog box` ? Do you mean a DialogFragment?

Comment: yes  DialogFragment

Comment: Then adapt the subject and the text in your post.

Comment: And why are you not reaction on onSaveInstanceState() ????